# melt giving several value columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2, melt

I am reading in parameter estimates from some results files that I would like to compare side by side in a table. But I cant get the dataframe to the structure that I want to have (Parameter name, Values(file1), Values(file2))

When I read in the files I get a wide dataframe with each parameter in a separate column that I would like to transform to "long" format using melt. But that gives only one column with values. Any idea on how to get several value columns without using a for loop?

```
paraA <- c(1,2)
paraB <- c(6,8)
paraC <- c(11,9)
Source <- c("File1","File2")
parameters <- data.frame(paraA,paraB,paraC,Source)

wrong_table <- melt(parameters, by="Source")
```

Comment: Perhaps manipulating `t(parameters)` a bit could give what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `melt` in combination with `cast` to get what you want. This is in fact the intended pattern of use, which is why the functions have the names they do:

```
m<-melt(parameters)
dcast(m,variable~Source)
#   variable File1 File2
# 1    paraA     1     2
# 2    paraB     6     8
# 3    paraC    11     9
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting @alexis's comment to an answer, transpose (`t()`) pretty much does what you want:

```
setNames(data.frame(t(parameters[1:3])), parameters[, "Source"])
#       File1 File2
# paraA     1     2
# paraB     6     8
# paraC    11     9
```

I've used `setNames` above to conveniently rename the resulting `data.frame` in one step.